# Why does formatting today’s date in Android Studio give 19700101?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.setTime( date );
    if (Calendar.MINUTE < 40) {
        if (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY == 0) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        }
        else
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
    }
    int z = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int w = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_nowbasedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_nowbasetime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");

    String baseDate_now = sdf_nowbasedate.format(z);
    String baseTime_now = sdf_nowbasetime.format(w)+ "00";

System.out.println(baseDate_now + " " + baseTime_now);
```

Result that I expect is "20180606 1200"(Because now time writing this article is 2018 June 6th, 1:12 PM (KST - I live in Korea)

But the result is "19700101 0900"

Why does this error happen?

Comment: Have you debugged the if else condition?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. `Date` and `Calendar` are outdated too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). BTW, it’s always dangerous to assume there’s nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass a `Date` to `sdf_nowbasedate.format(Date)` instead int ("z" or "w")
as you are using Calendar you must get the Date

```
String baseDate_now = sdf_nowbasedate.format(cal.getTime());
String baseTime_now = sdf_nowbasetime.format(cal.getTime())+ "00";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int z = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int w = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
SimpleDateFormat sdf_nowbasedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String baseDate_now = sdf_nowbasedate.format(z);
```

First off, this code can't even compile.  There is no format function that takes an integer as a parameter.  It takes a date.  But assuming you're actually somehow making a date out of that number-  that would make your date basically a few dozen ms off the epoch time, which is Jan 1, 1970.

Instead, pass the date in to format directly.

Comment: FWIW, it can compile and produces this result since there's `format(Object)` in `java.text.DateFormat` / `java.text.Format` superclasses that takes any `Number` as millis-since-epoch value.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

The other answers have correctly explained why your code gave you a date of January 1, 1970. I should like to contribute the modern correct version of the code. I think you’re after something like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd HHmm");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul"));
    if (zdt.getMinute() < 40) {
        zdt = zdt.minusHours(1);
    }
    ZonedDateTime wholeHours = zdt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    String baseNow = wholeHours.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(baseNow);
```

Running this just now (00:52 in South Korea) it printed:

> 20180607 0000

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, because `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are all long outdated and poorly designed and `java.time` is so much nicer to work with.

There seems to be another bug in your code. `Calendar.MINUTE` and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` are constants with values 12 and 11, so `Calendar.MINUTE < 40` will always be true, and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY == 0` will never be. Instead you probably intended `cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` and similarly for hour of day. Lesson to learn: with the old classes it is very easy to make errors, also some that go unnoticed and others that are hard to pinpoint. I do recommend you avoid those classes.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.